# Best example for mixins in .NET

Tags: programming-languages, c#, .net

I want to present the concept of mixins and their implementation in .NET.

The way they work in .NET is you add extension methods on an interface and decorate classes with said interface.

What would be the best examples for this pattern (other than linq)?

Comment: Just to clarify are you looking for the abstract base class sample or is it something else? Term [mixin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin) seems to be unfamiliar at least in .NET.

Comment: No, not abstract base classes. Mixins allow for a form of multiple inheritance. Say you have a bat. It's a specialization of the mammal class. But it can also fly. A mixin would allow you to implement the flight logic in one single place, and decorate all the classes you want (e.g. bats, owles, bugs, etc.)

Comment: A mixin is a class that is parameterized by its superclass. I don't really see what extension methods have to do with that. Can you explain?

Comment: There are various ways of implementing the mixin pattern, and it takes different forms in different programming languages (the pattern being very loosely defined). Basically it's a way of adding utility code to a class by sidestepping "normal" inheritance, since you need that for something else entirely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, "mixin" is a Ruby concept for handling multiple inheritance limitations, and does not have a built-in comparable way of doing it in C#, VB.NET, or Java.

Your suggestion of adding extension methods to an interface is an interesting one, and would provide much of the benefit of a mixin. I've never actually seen anyone do it that way before, so I'll have to put that in my bag of tricks...

As far as an example, I think the one you put in your comment above isn't a bad one; demonstrating that a Bat is a mammal that can fly.  Without making your own contrived example like that, I can't think of anyplace where this just "occurs" in any of the core .NET libraries, other than Linq (sort of, though even IEnumerable requires that you define the `GetEnumerator` method in the implementing class, so it isn't a purely "empty" interface with only extension methods.)

Is there a problem with presenting your own contrived example?

Comment: "mixin" is a pretty generic concept which isn't specific to any modern language.

Comment: Agreed the concept of a mixin isn't language specific. I just assumed (possibly falsely) that the original question was talking about "ruby style mixins" since it is the most "modern" language that i know of that supports them.

Comment: Any language with both type polymorphism and inheritance supports mixins- even Java. It's been found in C++ since 1995 at least.

Comment: I hope those are scare quotes! *Modern* isn't what comes to mind when talking about a language that isn't just dynamically typed, but also allows any type to be monkey-patched.

Comment: @Doval I can see why you don't like those features, but I can't imagine it's because they're not "modern". Dynamic typing (as implemented in Ruby) and monkey patching aren't really what come to mind when I think of "old" languages.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if it's the best example, but I've got an example of using extension methods to approximate mixins on my blog: http://horsdal.blogspot.com/2009/05/dci-in-c.html?m=0

Please note that you don't really get mixins by doing this, just something that sort of like mixins from the client codes perspective.

Comment: "Please note that you don't really get mixins by doing this, just something that sort of like mixins from the client codes perspective." What's the difference, and perhaps more importantly, what's the definition of mixins you're using? Everyone seems to have a different one.

Comment: @Doval: I would imagine that the difference is that a true mixin will have access to a class's internals.  Extension methods do not.  Extension methods are just syntactic sugar for static method calls, so all they have access to is a class's external API.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Interesting. When you say "a class's internals", do you mean something internal to the mixin, or the internals of the class being decorated?

Comment: @Doval: Extension methods won't have access to anything that a class's public methods don't already provide.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Right. I was asking about mixins. If mixins access the internals of the class they decorate, that creates a tight coupling not only between that mixin and the class, but also between all other mixins that can access that class's internals. Is that right?

Comment: @Doval: I guess what I'm trying to say is that anything you can do with an extension method, you can already do with the public API of an ordinary class anyway, albeit with different syntax.  Not directly answering your question, but without access to class internals I see any interaction between classes via the external API as ordinary composition, unless I'm missing something blindingly obvious about mixins.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Agreed, I guess I was just shocked that anyone would want mixins to access private variables and wanted to double-check I'm understanding that correctly. I was just making sure I'm understanding that correctly.

Comment: +1 @RobertHarvey's comments on what extension methods do not give you. When I say that this does not give you mixins I'm thinking about mixins as a mechanism similar to mixins in Ruby or traits in Scala.

Answer (score 1):

I've been working on an open source Mixin framework for C# [pMixins](http://pmixins.apphb.com/).  It leverages partial classes and code generators to wire in the Mixin class into the Target:

```
//Mixin - Class that contains members that should be injected into other classes.
public class Mixin
{
   // This method should be in several class
   public void Method(){ }
}

//Target (Note: That it is partial) - Add members from Mixin
[pMixn(Target = typeof(Mixin)]
public partial class Target{}


//Example of using Target
public class Consumer
{
    public void Example()
    {
        var target = new Target();

        // can call mixed in method
        target.Method();

        // can implicitly convert Target to Mixin
        Mixin m = new Target();
        m.Method();
   }
}
```

Comment: Most examples of mixins that I've seen are either of the "Fooing the Bar" variety like this one, or involve [animal taxonomies](http://colinmackay.co.uk/2008/02/24/mixins-in-c-30/), neither of which adequately illustrates how mixins might be useful in a practical coding scenario.

Comment: @RobertHarver - Do you have an example of a practical coding scenario?

Comment: I don't.  See http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/135799/best-example-for-mixins-in-net/238508?noredirect=1#comment478944_135893